# Get metrics from Linux scale sets

Tags: azure

Inside the portal, under the Monitoring section, I can get performance metrics such as CPU percentage, in a visual form. How can I get (export) this data in a table format? 
I have tried setting up an OMS account in order to connect my scale set, but it does not have support for scale sets yet, only for individual VMs.

Comment: export data to storage account and ingest with oms

Comment: how can I do that? When I pick my resource group, the Resource type becomes non-editable, and I can only export other types of data, not performance metrics.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Monitor to export metrics to a storage account (blobs). This configuration is set for each individual resource.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-metrics